# vncserver-x11 binary not found!

Tags: x11, apt, package-management, vnc

In which package I can find `vncserver-x11` binary? I installed `x11vnc` and I found only `x11vnc` binary.I don't have any package named `vncserver-x11` in repository.

$`uname -a`

`Linux 3.2.0-67-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: To help us help you....please identify OS, distribution, and version number.

Comment: @mdpc: Sorry, Edited the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no package containing a `vncserver-x11` binary in Ubuntu (or Debian). You can always check the [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=vncserver-x11&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) to find files inside packages.

A `vncserver-x11` binary [is part of RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/misc/reference/vncserver-x11.html). You can download Debian-compatible installers for RealVNC [from their website](http://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/latest/), which are likely to work on Ubuntu. The "generic installers" will probably work too.